# active state menu javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble to setup the active state for my menu using URL recognition. What I'm looking to achieve is having the `<a href="">` to change to `<a id="active" href ="">` if you're on the page it links to. This what I have done so far and it seems not working.

Let me know if you have any idea and thanks all for your help!

```
 $(function(){   
  var url = window.location.href;   
  var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);   
   $('.ActiveMenu a[href*="'+page+'"]');   
   $(this).attr({ id: 'active'});});


  <ul id="menu">
   <li id="Link1" class="ActiveMenu"><a href="URL1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li id="Link2" class="ActiveMenu"><a href="URL2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li id="Link3" class="ActiveMenu"><a href="URL3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I think `change/add the class instead of id` like `$(this).addClass('active')`

Comment: If your willing to use PHP its much easier imo with it. Just adding this to your code will do the trick `<?php if($currentUrl == "http://www.google.com/") { echo "id='active'"; } ?>` then just add 
                                                           `$currentUrl = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in your config file. But if you want to take the javascript road give me a second to think and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the issue is that your **function doesn't know what $(this) is**. Instead, you should set **target to the correct element** and then add a class to it. You shouldn't use id because you should only have one id and it should be a unique identifier, not a state. Class is better suited for it. Let me know if this works for you! :)

**DEMO**

```
 $(function(){   
  var url = window.location.href;   
  var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);   
   target = $('.ActiveMenu a[href*="'+page+'"]');   
   $(target).addClass('active');
});


  <ul id="menu">
   <li id="Link1" class="ActiveMenu"><a href="URL1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li id="Link2" class="ActiveMenu"><a href="URL2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li id="Link3" class="ActiveMenu"><a href="URL3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add/change the class name instead of Id

```
$(function(){   
   var url = window.location.href;   
   var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);   
   var currentPage=$('.ActiveMenu a[href*="'+page+'"]');   
   currentPage.addClass('active');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
$(this).attr("id","active");
```

Comment: The OP syntax is just as valid as yours.  attr can take a jquery object.  See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes)